# (For all instances of) Django model field 'moves', it maps to the same Move class instance

Tags: python, django, model, field

heres my model

```
class Game(models.Model):
    ...
    moves = Moves()

class Moves():
    moves = []
    ...
```

After creating about 50 objects of Game, all of them point to the same Moves() object. I need different instances of Moves for each object.

Here are game objects and their id along with moves:

```
1 :  <games.models.Moves object at 0x9f1474c>
2 :  <games.models.Moves object at 0x9f1474c>
3 :  <games.models.Moves object at 0x9f1474c>
...
```

Comment: `Moves` is not a subclass of `ModelField` in this code. Do you know how to create custom model fields? And why you need it? It's not clear in your question and it's rather complicated https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/. We can help you, but you have to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both `Game.moves` and `Moves.moves` are class attributes and not instance attributes. This means that they are initialized only when class is created and not upon instance creation. To get the desired behavior use `__init__` method:

```
class Game(models.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        self.moves = Moves()

class Moves():

    def __init__(self):
        self.moves = []
```

Here is what I get from interactive Python interpreter:

```
>>> class Game(models.Model):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.moves = Moves()
... 
>>> class Moves():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.moves = []
... 
>>> Game().moves
<__main__.Moves instance at 0x7f4ee1b9f560>
>>> Game().moves
<__main__.Moves instance at 0x7f4ee1b9f680>
>>> Game().moves
<__main__.Moves instance at 0x7f4ee1b9f560>
```

You can not simply create other instance attributes like Django does with `Field` subclasses defined as class attributes of `Model` subclasses.
Django provides a `metaclass` for `Model` which scans class attributes and converts them to instance attributes but only if they subclass `Field`.

Comment: Throws an error. 'GameAdmin.list_display[5], 'moves' is not a callable or an attribute of 'GameAdmin' or found in the model 'Game'.'

Comment: @Ryan I don't see the rest of your code and I'm not a wizard. In your code class `Moves` is not a subclass of `ModelField` so don't expect it to behave like a model field. I can only tell you that my code is the correct way to get 50 instances of class `Moves` instead of 1 shared between 50 instances of class `Game`. That was your question. I can help you to get forward but for this question it's all that can be said.

Comment: The error is comes from your code - I don't see any GameAdmin.list_display[5] in my answer. I can suspect that you have that line in your `admin.py` but I can't keep guessing what's the rest of your code and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It worked. apparently my Moves class was inhereting from model, when I needed to use 'object'. Yes I know about custom fields, but in this case I don't need it. I just need  the Move class to be a normal Python class.